# Oracle TNS-12505 Error

Tags: oracle, listener, tnsnames, sid, oracle8i

I am working with Oracle and what I had to do was to export the existing database to new installation.

I have installed  new oracle client 8.1 (Previous was 8.0), I have successfully imported all the instance of database,(Users,Roles, everything).

Basically it is Server and from other individual clients it shares data.
What I am facing a problem now is , 
any XYZ client can not varify its login credentials. I am getting two different types of erros. below I will mention:

1. TNS-12505: TNS:listener could not resolve SID given in connect descriptor
2. TNS-12500: TNS:listener failed to start a dedicated server process
    TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
     TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

I have tried almost every option by googling the specified errors.

I have configured the TNSNAMES.ora and LISTENER.ora at server installation and test , they are working well.

But the issue is when I connect through client after configuring TNSNAMES using "Net8 Assitant" it shows the following error.

```
TNS-12505: TNS:listener could not resolve SID given in connect descriptor
```

I will try to attach the Configuration files data:
**TNSNAMES.ora @ Server**

```
# D:\ORANT\NETWORK\ADMIN\TNSNAMES.ORA Configuration   File:d:\orant\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle Net8 Assistant

 DATA =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (SOURCE_ROUTE = OFF)
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.109)(PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = data)
       (GLOBAL_NAME = data)
       (SRVR = DEDICATED)
     )
   )
```

**LISTENER.ora @ Server**

```
# D:\ORANT\NETWORK\ADMIN\LISTENER.ORA Configuration File:d:\orant\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle Net8 Assistant

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rwr_mis)(PORT = 1521))
    (PROTOCOL_STACK =
      (PRESENTATION = TTC)
      (SESSION = NS)
    )
  )
```

And Finally **TNSNAMES.ora @ Client**

```
# C:\ORANT\NET80\ADMIN\TNSNAMES.ORA Configuration File:C:\orant\net80\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle Net8 Assistant

data =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS =
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (Host = 192.168.0.109)
          (Port = 1521)
        )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

From above settings I am gettin gthe followin gerror at Client side:

***TNS-12505: TNS:listener could not resolve SID given in connect descriptor***

kindly suggest any solution, I will be very thankful .

Comment: **TNSNAMES.ora @ Client** : `(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = data)`

Comment: It Worked. same suggestion I was going to ask.

Answer (score 0):

update TNSNAMES.ora @ client with following code

```
DATA =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.109)(PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = data)
     )
   )
```